# How do I do a Javascript Redirect in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, url, redirect

I have a asp.net webform with a button. The OnClientClick event is wired to a javascript function.

I need this function to redirect the current page to this page.

After much reading is have tried all the following, but to no avail:

```
           var url = "http://www.google.com";
           document.location = url; //Doesn't Work
           document.location.href = url; //Doesn't Work
           window.location = url; //Doesnt Work
           window.location.href = url; //Doesnt Work
```

Any Help or advice are welcome.

Ps. I am entering the JS function as my alert message pops up

Comment: Above code that you mentioned should work... Could you post code of event and handler for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have somewhere on your code a Javascript Error, that stop the execution, because as the other say, this code that you say that "doesnt work", it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in a html page and it worked fine.

> function go() { alert();     var
>   url = "http://www.google.com";
>              document.location.href = url; //Doesn't Work }

Just look at the page source and see whether onClientClick is calling your js function

Answer (score 1):

Try putting **return false;** after your function in the OnClientClick

e.g. `OnClientClick="yourfunction();return false;"`

Comment: I didn't have any errors on my page like other posters mentioned. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `location.replace(myUrl);`, but `document.location.href` should really work.